# Build Libraries for Distribution” into ”Yes” Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, legacy

In my project I have enabled the Build Libraries for Distribution” into ”Yes”  into my SDK build setting, to prevent swift upgrades from causing a problem for third party libraries. In this case, When I Build with the project for SDK, I have set legacy mode but I am facing issue like below:

**The legacy does not support Build Libraries for Distribution” into ”Yes”.**

How to fix this?  I can able to build the project new build system instead of legacy mode

The reason for setting legacy mode is When I set a new build system and prepare to build I am getting this below error. To fix this I am using legacy mode

```
Multiple commands produce '/Path/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework':
 1) Target 'GoogleUtilities-00567490' has create directory command with output '/Path//IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'
 2) Target 'GoogleUtilities-54e75ca4' has create directory command with output '/Path//IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/iphoneos/GoogleUtilities.framework'
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this build system issue is to explicitly add all the needed GoogleUtilities subspecs to the `Podfile`. See the `Podfile.lock` file to get the list. Full details at https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4087